# Keycloak - remove all groups synced from LDAP

Tags: ldap, keycloak, usergroups

After entering **LDAP Groups DN** field under **User Federation** => **Ldap** => **LDAP Mappers** => **groups** , and doing **Sync LDAP Groups to Keycloak** , I realized more than 1000 groups got downloaded.

I tried updating the **LDAP Filter** field (as shown in the below screenshot) and ran the Sync again but all the 1000 groups are still there instead of Keycloak only keeping the Filtered ones and removing all other groups.

How to remove all groups to start clean or make Keycloak only keep the groups based on the **LDAP Filter** used?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiLln.png)

When I added the **LDAP Filter** I was expecting to have Keycloak remove all other groups synced before and only keep the ones matching the filter, but instead, it kept them all.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you use "remove imported" action on the user federation settings to remove all users together with all groups imported from ldap.

Comment: I tried that before and it seems to only be removing the Users while keeping the Groups intact.